# Vertical scroll bar in div which is a child of css grid column

Tags: css, css-grid

I am new to CSS grid, I have a nested [grid layout page](https://codepen.io/saravananr/pen/OvbaVK). I could not get a scroll bar for grid child **`div.fieldsContainer`**.

```css
html,body,
.wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
}

.header{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.footer{
  background: lightpink;
}

.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 300px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fieldTypes{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
}

.fieldTypes .search{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fieldTypes .fieldsContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(70px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.card{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fieldTypes">
      <div class="search">search</div>
      <div class="fieldsContainer">
        <div class="card">1</div>
        <div class="card">2</div>
        <div class="card">3</div>
        <div class="card">4</div>
        <div class="card">5</div>
        <div class="card">6</div>
        <div class="card">7</div>
        <div class="card">8</div>
        <div class="card">9</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inndercontent">
      innder content
    </div>
    <div class="graphs">
      graphs
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No code. No answer. Sorry mate. Please add a [mcve] - பிரவீன்

Comment: Ok @PraveenKumar I find really hard to press crtl+k every time, to add one line of code. so that prepared the codepen sample added it here. or Is there any easy way to add, please share if you know.

Comment: Use `Ctrl + M`. That's why I gave you the documentation bro! :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One solution would be to set `overflow-y:auto` on the parent ( `.fieldTypes` ) and `overflow-y:scroll` on `.fieldsContainer`

There is no ' story ' behind this. Just that you have to set a default overflow for the parent to accept it, and then specify overflow-y:scroll( as you want vertical scroll ) on the child.

```css
html,body,
.wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
}

.header{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.footer{
  background: lightpink;
}

.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr 300px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fieldTypes{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 1fr;
  overflow-y:auto;/*added*/
}

.fieldTypes .search{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fieldTypes .fieldsContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(70px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  overflow-y:scroll;/*added*/
}

.card{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="fieldTypes">
      <div class="search">search</div>
      <div class="fieldsContainer">
        <div class="card">1</div>
        <div class="card">2</div>
        <div class="card">3</div>
        <div class="card">4</div>
        <div class="card">5</div>
        <div class="card">6</div>
        <div class="card">7</div>
        <div class="card">8</div>
        <div class="card">9</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
        <div class="card">10</div>
        <div class="card">11</div>
        <div class="card">12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inndercontent">
      innder content
    </div>
    <div class="graphs">
      graphs
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, But it will useful to me if you share the story behind this working code. So that it will help me out in future.

Comment: @SaravananRamupillai There is no ' story ' behind this. Just that you have to set a default overflow for the parent to accept it, and then specify overflow-y:scroll( as you want vertical scroll ) on the child. More information you can find on the web by looking into overflow css style

Comment: @MihaiT Why isn't `overflow-y: scroll` on the child sufficient? Why do we need a `overflow-y: auto` on the parent?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a more reduced case (to cut through the irrelevant parts)

```css
html, body, .A {
  height: 100%; /* matters */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.A {
  max-height: 300px; /* matters */
  display: grid; /* matters */
  overflow: hidden; /* matters */
}

.B {
  display: grid; /* matters */
  overflow-y: auto; /* matters */
}

.D {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* matters */
}

.C {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #07f;
}

.E {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C">search</div>
    <div class="D">
      <div class="E">1</div>
      <div class="E">2</div>
      <div class="E">3</div>
      <div class="E">4</div>
      <div class="E">5</div>
      <div class="E">6</div>
      <div class="E">7</div>
      <div class="E">8</div>
      <div class="E">9</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
      <div class="E">10</div>
      <div class="E">11</div>
      <div class="E">12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Would recommend this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent's height to `100vh`. Then `overflow-y: scroll` will work on the children.

See this example (based on the reduced case answer).

```css
html, body, .A {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.A {
  height: 100vh; /* matters */
  display: grid; /* matters */
}

.B {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #07f;
}

.C {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* matters */
}

.D {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">search</div>
  <div class="C">
    <div class="D">1</div>
    <div class="D">2</div>
    <div class="D">3</div>
    <div class="D">4</div>
    <div class="D">5</div>
    <div class="D">6</div>
    <div class="D">7</div>
    <div class="D">8</div>
    <div class="D">9</div>
    <div class="D">10</div>
    <div class="D">11</div>
    <div class="D">12</div>
    <div class="D">10</div>
    <div class="D">11</div>
    <div class="D">12</div>
    <div class="D">10</div>
    <div class="D">11</div>
    <div class="D">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```